# Create pypy process

Tags: python, process, pypy, search-path

I would like to create a process which runs PyPy. I tried the following and it works:

```
import os
os.chdir('<path-to-pypy-download>/bin/')
os.execl('pypy', 'pypy', '-c', 'print "Hi!"')
```

However, when I remove the `chdir` as:

```
import os
os.execl('<path-to-pypy-download>/bin/pypy', 'pypy', '-c', 'print "Hi!"')
```

I get:

```
debug: WARNING: Library path not found, using compiled-in sys.path.
debug: WARNING: 'sys.prefix' will not be set.
debug: WARNING: Make sure the pypy binary is kept inside its tree of files.
debug: WARNING: It is ok to create a symlink to it from somewhere else.
debug: OperationError:
debug:  operror-type: ImportError
debug:  operror-value: No module named os
```

Please, does anyone know how to spawn a PyPy process without changing the working directory?

Comment: Have you tried passing the full path for `arg0` as well as for `path`? Because presumably it's using (the RPython/compile-to-C equivalent of) `sys.argv[0]` to find its library path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be correct (in which case I'll delete it), but I'm pretty sure that all you need to do is:

```
os.execl('<path-to-pypy-download>/bin/pypy', 
         '<path-to-pypy-download>/bin/pypy', '-c', 'print "Hi!"')
```

In other words, pass the full path for [`arg0` as well as `path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl).

Why? Well, when PyPy starts up, it's got to be using (the RPython/compiled-to-C equivalent of) [`sys.argv[0]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) to find the path to a custom stdlib. What else could it use? Which is of course just copied from the `char *argv[]` argument passed to the interpreter's `main` function. When you let the OS launch a program for you, it will put the full path in there. But when you explicitly set it with `execl`, it will just copy whatever you gave it.

It's actually a *bit* more complicated than this—it does a `readlink` (to allow symlinks) and an `abspath` (to allow itself to be run by relative path—as in your first example). But the basic idea is the same.

As a side note, you might want to consider using a fully-installed PyPy instead of a run-out-of-build-tree PyPy, in which case its `sys.prefix` will be set up properly so it won't need this.